# Local DB in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, database

After a few years, I have returned to writing in C# and I am really struggling here - I would like to have my app to have a local SQL database. I have added Service-based database and "Database1.mdf" was added to my project. I created a table and added some data just to see if it is working but I cannot connect to it. I tried numerous connection strings with no success (Server not accessible).

Do I need to run something else in the background? I thought that I might have a local database and with .NET client I can access it, and I hoped it would work whenever I bring my application (also not requiring any SQL server running). Is that wrong?

Comment: The sql server owns the mdf file a you do not have permissions to access the file directly.  You should always connect to the sql server database and use the database name in sql instead of the mdf file.  Connect to the sql server instance using the same name that is in the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) login window and use the database name that is in the SSMS explorer.  Either make  it the default database name or put a "USE DATABASE NAME" into your sql statements.

Comment: you could have been using SQL compact, and now you've come back its a different version

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, ah so I cannot do that as with SQL Compact Edition, i.e. to have basically a portable app that has its own SQL database in its folder and works independetly?

Comment: The local database can follow the app around, I've made several that do as you describe.  You just connect as if it were a regular DB

Comment: it can be that the DB portion of visual studio is keeping the db open so the app cant use it

Comment: @ferday well but does the computer always need to have SQL server installed?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've sent mine to employees with work computers (nothing fun installed) and they've all worked.  Good question though if someone has a definitive answer it could help me as well

Comment: I don't have 2015 but there was a bug in older VS that would allow you to connect compact to a server, but I thought that was fixed.

Comment: @jdweng So how should I proceed then? I am usin SqlConnection and trying to connect to the file which obviously does not work. How to connect through the server then?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require any SQL server, take a look at SQLite. This is lite SQL database engine. Database is just one file. C# has a great library to SQLite on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/profiles/mistachkin

SQLite is widely used, event in Android (as a native db engine).

Comment: So I cannot do that in VS Express 2015 with its built in tools?

Comment: See www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio 2015 DOESN'T HAVE any built-in tools for SQLite. But I might be wrong. I have been using this Nuget package since always.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i use to connect.  it appears as a `Data Connection` in Server Explorer.

```
string con2 = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\jobfile_2017.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

when i first started working with these, i used [this source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx) [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx)

it works on PC's that i have nothing installed (not even office) but as i said i'd be interested to know of any shortcomings of this method

Answer (score 0):

I experiencing same problem and decided to move mdf file to static c:\db directory. Connection string was changed to incorporate new file location (AttachDbFile).

But AttachDbFile has some issues also (by some reason one table in db is inaccesible and error is access denied).

So I decided to move to Sqlite. LocalDb has many issues to work with. I read good note to resolve problem: in command line stop/remove/start name of instance. But it nuissance.

Wish you good luck to work with these db files.